# SQS Queue in laravel console

Tags: laravel, terminal, console, kernel, amazon-sqs

I have written code in app->Console->Commands->sendMessage.php

In Kernel.php, I have declared my class.

When i try to execute my command in Terminal, I receive `403 Forbidden` response.

If I run the same code from sendMessageController.php everything works fine, since it access URL from Apache.

I do not have clear idea about running in Console commands.

① app->Console->Commands->sendMessage.php code

```php
$region = 'ap-northeast-1';
$version = '2012-11-05';
$queueURL = 'sqs-Queue URL';

$client = SqsClient::factory([
    'credentials' => array(
    'key'    => false,
    'secret' => false ),
    'region' => $region, //replace it with your region
    'version' => $version
]);

$params = [
    'DelaySeconds' => 10,
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        "Title" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "The Guide to the Galaxy"
        ],
        "Author" => [
            'DataType' => "String",
            'StringValue' => "Galaxy"
        ]
    ],
    'MessageBody' => "Please send this message. This is First SQS Test Queue version 1.2",
    'QueueUrl' => $queueURL
];

$sentMessage = $client->sendMessage($params);
```

② kernel.php code

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\sendMessage::class
    ];
}
```

Error Displayed in Terminal :

> [Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException] Error executing "SendMessage" AWS
>   HTTP error: Client error: Posted URL  resulted in a `403 Forbid den`
>   response.  AccessDenied (client): Access to the resource URL is
>   denied.

Comment: Anyone Suggest Any Idea for this issue.

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: not yet. would you suggest any work arounds?

Comment: Hi. Anyone suggest any work around for this problem.

Comment: @kumaran I'm not sure this is a Laravel issue; it sounds like you don't have the right IAM permissions to use this queue. Are you able to check your IAM credentials and the policy assigned to the user or role you're using?